# Mobile site question list has extra space above the question text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-site

The mobile site seems to have extra spacing which is pushing the question text **way** out of alignment.

Here it is on Firefox Android (logged in) And on Chrome Android (Cleared cookies and not logged in)::
[image: Firefox Android]
[image: Google Chrome]

And repro'd on desktop with 'mobile' turned on:
[image: Desktop]

It appears that the `.votes` CSS class is missing a `display: inline-block`. Adding it back fixes the issue:

[image: Display: inline-block]

Comment: This has now been fixed as per the [Meta Stack Exchange Post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276065/179041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) This should be fixed now. Thanks for reporting!